# Printer status using powershell

Tags: powershell

Do you know of a way to check printer status using powershell. I tried get-printer command but it does not show me the status of my printers connected on a network. I need to see when my printers fail and then have some script send me an email that "x" printer failed. Any Ideas? (also I am using v1)

Comment: No v-4 and v-5?

Comment: no my company has v-1

Comment: Use `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_printer` and check the result's PrinterStatus

Comment: Or `Get-CIMInstance -Class CIM_Printer`.

Answer (score 3):

The default output of Get-Printer does not show the status, but you can try this:

```
Get-Printer | Select Name, PrinterStatus
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add this

```
Get-Printer | Select Name, PrinterStatus | WHERE PrinterStatus -eq Normal
```